# Can I override both abstract accessors (get/set) at one time in Python?

Tags: python, properties

I am trying to write code like the following:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class C(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def x(self):
        pass

    @x.setter
    @abstractmethod
    def x(self, val):
        pass

class D(C):
    @C.x.getter
    def x(self):
        pass

    @C.x.setter
    def x(self, val):
        pass

def examine_property(p):
    print('get', p.fget, getattr(p.fget, '__isabstractmethod__', False) if p.fget is not None else None)
    print('set', p.fset, getattr(p.fset, '__isabstractmethod__', False) if p.fset is not None else None)
    print('del', p.fdel, getattr(p.fdel, '__isabstractmethod__', False) if p.fdel is not None else None)

print("C.x:")
examine_property(C.x)
print("D.x:")
examine_property(D.x)
```

But it does not seem to work:

```
C.x:
get <function C.x at 0x1017af2e0> True
set <function C.x at 0x1017af380> True
del None None
D.x:
get <function C.x at 0x1017af2e0> True
set <function D.x at 0x1017af4c0> False
del None None
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it simply impossible to override both both abstract accessors (get/set) at one time?

Why is the getter on `D.x` still using the abstract `C.x` implementation?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here isn't specific to abstract methods, you'd have the same issue with any property object defined on a base class. The issue is that you using the wrong reference when you are defining the setter on `D`, and you *don't actually need to reference `C.x` here*.

Imagine a cupboard with a broken push-broom in it. You've had it for a long time, but the shaft is cracked and the bristles are falling out. A long time ago someone marked it with the letter C but you forgot why, it's that old.

You want to repair it by replacing the cracked shaft with a new shaft and attach a new broom head with bristles, and once that’s done you’ll call the broom *Dustdevil* because it’ll tackle cleaning like no other!

Just bare with me, you’ll see the point in a bit.

You have your new broom handle ready and the new broom head is nearby. You take the old broom, still marked with C, from the cupboard and you detach the old handle from the broom head, the handle that's cracked, and toss the handle back into the cupboard. You attach the new handle to the old head. Job halfway done! Before you can continue however, you are interrupted by someone knocking at your front door, so you put the result of your repair job against the wall next to the cupboard for a bit so you can go see who it is.

It turns out it’s just a door-to-door broom-salesman, named Rodney. To make it clear you are not in the market for their wares, you told them about your new broom, how you are going to name it 'Dustdevil', and you talked a bit about what makes a good broom. Rodney then talked about someone they knew once, someone named Trigger and [how they got a *medal* for taking care of their broom for 20 years](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LAh8HryVaeY)! But in the end the salesman had to leave without having made a sale.

So you return to the cupboard to continue your repair. You take the new broom head, and you take the cracked handle from the cupboard, and attach it to the new broom head. You are done, so you write a big D on the new broom head, where you can see it when you use the broom.

When you try sweeping with the new broom, however, you start noticing that the handle is still cracked, and that there's a letter C on the handle still. **What happened** you ask?

What happened is that you should just have attached the new broom handle to the new broom head and forget about the old broom in the cupboard, altogether! After all, when you do succeed in replacing all the parts, It's not the same broom anymore, just like the [ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus) you no longer are sweeping with the parts you started out with.

You need to do the same with the `property` object. When you are replacing both the getter and the setter, **you don't need the old property here**:

```
class D(C):
    @property
    def x(self):
        pass

    @x.setter
    def x(self, val):
        pass
```

When you use the `@property` decorator, the result is a new `property()` instance with a getter attached, stored as a local variable using the name of the decorated getter function. You can then attach more hook functions for the setter and deleter by using that local name as a starting point for further `.setter`, `.deleter` and even `.getter` decorators, which each in turn produce a *new* `property()` instance with everything copied across from the old but with a replacement hook function for one of the hooks.

Your specific mistake was to ignore the new property object with the replacement getter attached, and instead you took the old property back out from the cupboard to replace a different part.

If you *do* need to keep *some* part of the property you constructed for `C` (e.g. because you have a deleter or a docstring to preserve), then you only need to reference `C.x` **once**, because a property object. The result is a new property object you can then attach a different setter to:

```
class D(C):
    @C.x.getter
    def x(self):
        pass

    # Use the new `x` property here!
    @x.setter
    def x(self, val):
        pass
```

Just keep chaining your property decorators to apply more changes to it.

Illustrating the latter with a *deleter* function included:

```
>>> from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
>>> def inspect_x(cls):
...     print(f'{cls.__name__}.x:')
...     print(f'  get: {cls.x.fget}, abstract:', cls.x.fget and getattr(cls.x.fget, "__isabstractmethod__", False))
...     print(f'  set: {cls.x.fset}, abstract:', cls.x.fset and getattr(cls.x.fset, "__isabstractmethod__", False))
...     print(f'  del: {cls.x.fdel}, abstract:', cls.x.fdel and getattr(cls.x.fdel, "__isabstractmethod__", False))
...
>>> class C(ABC):
...     @property
...     @abstractmethod
...     def x(self):
...         pass
...     @x.setter
...     @abstractmethod
...     def x(self, val):
...         pass
...     @x.deleter
...     @abstractmethod
...     def x(self):
...         pass
...
>>> class D(C):
...     @C.x.getter
...     def x(self):
...         pass
...     @x.setter
...     def x(self, val):
...         pass
...     # note: **the deleter is still the original
...
>>> inspect_x(C)
C.x:
  get: <function C.x at 0x1017af240>, abstract: True
  set: <function C.x at 0x1017aede0>, abstract: True
  del: <function C.x at 0x1017af560>, abstract: True
>>> inspect_x(D)
D.x:
  get: <function D.x at 0x1017af1a0>, abstract: False
  set: <function D.x at 0x1017af600>, abstract: False
  del: <function C.x at 0x1017af560>, abstract: True
```

Comment: If I right understood the mechanic of @property decorator only  1-st overridden accessor should been declared with ancestor class prefix, since this first decorator usage will create new property declaration in target class, so to override other accessors we already should using the property of target class.

Comment: @М.Ю.Брызгалов exactly.